# I lost my iPad, but someone is now using my Kindle account to download books

Tags: ipad

Unfortunately I cannot track the device with the Find my Iphone feature, however, the person who took my iPad is using it to download books. Is there any way I can track the device using the kindle app?

Comment: I really hope that the Kindle app doesn't track user locations (even if it would be convenient in your case).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the Kindle app does not do any tracking. However you can remove it from your Amazon account and prevent them from downloading any more books.